# Issue with Eclipselink and @XmlRef

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am using Eclipselink 2.3.2 as my [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider. I have created a generic list which consists of a list of items and a set of Pagination Links.

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "listdata")
public class ListEntity<T> {

    @XmlElementRef
    public List<T> data;

    @XmlElementRef
    public PaginationLinks links;

    public ListEntity(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ListEntity() {
    }

}
```

My actual Entity

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="authorization")
public class AuthorizationDTO {

    @XmlElement 
    public String referenceNumber;

}
```

So, after creation of the list, when I try to marshall it, I get the following error. Works fine with @XmlElement for List data but obviously cannot be used as it creates the Object representation

```java
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-50006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException

Exception Description: Invalid XmlElementRef on property data on class com.ofss.fc.botg.infra.model.ListEntity. Referenced Element not declared.
```

Answer (score 5):

The `@XmlElementRef` annotation has the following requirements (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html):

- *If the collection item type (for collection property) or property type (for single valued property) is `JAXBElement`, then `@XmlElementRef.name()` and `@XmlElementRef.namespace()` must point an element factory method with an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation in a class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` (usually `ObjectFactory` class generated by the schema compiler) :*

  - *`@XmlElementDecl.name()` must equal `@XmlElementRef.name()`*
  - *`@XmlElementDecl.namespace()` must equal `@XmlElementRef.namespace()`.*
- *If the collection item type (for collection property) or property type (for single valued property) is not `JAXBElement`, then the type referenced by the property or field must be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.*

---

Since `ListEntity` will be processed as a class and not a type the `data` field will be treated as having type `Object` and therefore the requirements for `@XmlElementRef` will not have been met resulting in the exception that you are seeing.

Comment: I had a similar issue consuming a .NET WCF Service from a jaxws generated client. In the end I had to ask for the offending property to be removed and it worked like a charm after the removal. Would it be better to use an array instead of a list for the response entity ?